# Java GUI drawing an image on mouse event

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface, graphics

I'm making a program where hovering over a grid will place an image into the cell hovered over. Currently I have it working so that only a color is filled in, but I have no idea how to make it so an image is drawn in instead. Here's my program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test
{
Image img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("img.gif");
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    new Test();
}
public Test()
{
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new PixelGrid());
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(364,357));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public class PixelGrid extends JPanel
{
    private List<Shape>grid,square;
    public PixelGrid()
    {
        grid=new ArrayList<>();
        square=new ArrayList<>();
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
            {
                for(Shape shape:grid)
                {
                    if(shape.contains(e.getPoint()))
                    square.add(shape);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }
        );
        for(int row=0;row<5;row++)
        {
            for(int col=0;col<5;col++)
            grid.add(new Rectangle(col*25+112,row*25+50,25,25));
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(112,50,237,50);
        g.drawLine(112,75,237,75);
        g.drawLine(112,100,237,100);
        g.drawLine(112,125,237,125);
        g.drawLine(112,150,237,150);
        g.drawLine(112,175,237,175);
        g.drawLine(112,50,112,175);
        g.drawLine(137,50,137,175);
        g.drawLine(162,50,162,175);
        g.drawLine(187,50,187,175);
        g.drawLine(212,50,212,175);
        g.drawLine(237,50,237,175);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        for(Shape cell:square)
        g2.fill(cell);
    }
}
}
```

I want to make the image "img" become the "pixel" that is filled in. However, I'm confused on how to do this as I don't think I can use for-each loops and Graphics2D. If anyone can help, thanks so much!

Comment: Use the `Graphics2D` [drawImage(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) method.

Answer (score 2):

Define ImageHolder class which has 2 fields shape and image.

```
class ImageHolder {
  Shape shape;
  Image img;

  public void paint(Graphics2D g2) {
    if (img!=null) {
      g2.drawImage(img);
    }
    else {
      g2.fill(shape);
    }
  }
}
```

Your grid should be List. On init all the ImageHolders have squares and null images. On click image is assigned to the clicked holder.

In the paintComponent() you just call the holder's paint() method

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this one.
all you need to do is repalce your `g2.fill(cell);` with  `g2.drawImage(img,cell.getBounds().x,cell.getBounds().y,null);`

[read drawimage api here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver))

```
for (Shape cell : square) {
     //g2.fill(cell);
     g2.drawImage(img,cell.getBounds().x,cell.getBounds().y,null);
     System.out.println(cell.getBounds().x);
}
```

however use `Dimention list` or `2D list` instead `Shape` in this case

complete code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("img.gif");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new PixelGrid());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(364, 357));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class PixelGrid extends JPanel {
     int x=0;
     int y=0;
        private List<Shape> grid, square;

        public PixelGrid() {
            grid = new ArrayList<>();
            square = new ArrayList<>();
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                    for (Shape shape : grid) {
                        if (shape.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                            square.add(shape);
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            );
            for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                    grid.add(new Rectangle(col * 25 + 112, row * 25 + 50, 25, 25));

                }
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            System.out.println(x);
            g.drawLine(112, 50, 237, 50);
            g.drawLine(112, 75, 237, 75);
            g.drawLine(112, 100, 237, 100);
            g.drawLine(112, 125, 237, 125);
            g.drawLine(112, 150, 237, 150);
            g.drawLine(112, 175, 237, 175);
            g.drawLine(112, 50, 112, 175);
            g.drawLine(137, 50, 137, 175);
            g.drawLine(162, 50, 162, 175);
            g.drawLine(187, 50, 187, 175);
            g.drawLine(212, 50, 212, 175);
            g.drawLine(237, 50, 237, 175);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            //g2.drawImage(img,x,y,null);
            for (Shape cell : square) {
                //g2.fill(cell);
                g2.drawImage(img,cell.getBounds().x,cell.getBounds().y,null);
                System.out.println(cell.getBounds().x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output>>

[image]

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by 2D List? Like List<List<Shape>>? Or should I not use shapes at all?

Comment: @user1804208 no problem about using shapes ,but i think may be collection is good in this case